# android: update scores according to the timer's milliseconds

Tags: android, performance, time, timer

There is a timer in the app coded as follows:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        if (game_pause ==false)
        {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            text_time.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);     

            if (milliseconds % 10 == 0)
            {
                update_score_level(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            text_time.setText("Paused!");
        }
    }
};
```

### Question:

The score will be updated for every `if (milliseconds % 10 == 0)`. However, coding in this way though the time runs smoothly, the update of score appears extremely not smooth (not linear speed, sometimes fast sometimes slow).

Would like to show this way:
0:00:100 ---> Score +1;
0:00:200 ---> Score +1;
0:00:300 ---> Score +1;
How could the above be modified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're bound for failure if you're running the above code **one thousand times per second**. And you'd have to, in order to hit the `milliseconds % 10` each time. Android is not an RTOS, so it'll miss quite a few of these updates.

Instead, calculate the time-based score (milliseconds/10) and add it to the base score. The following is just pseudo code, but it should get you in the right direction:

```
long currentScore = 0;
long lastStartTimeMillis = 0;
boolean isPaused = true;

void resumeGame() {
    // remember the last time the game was started/resumed
    lastStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    isPaused = false;
}

void pauseGame() {
    isPaused = true;
    // ms of last game run
    long runningTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - latStartTimeMillis;
    // add it to the base score
    currentScore += runningTime / 10L;
}

long getCurrentScore() {
    if( isPaused ) {
        return currentScore;
    } else {
        long runningTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - latStartTimeMillis;
        return currentScore + runningTime / 10L;
    }
}
```

When you display the current score, you can just use `getCurrentScore()`, which automatically adds the time-based score if it's running. When pausing the game, you add the time-based score to the base score, so it displays correctly.

With this code in place, you can update the display far fewer times, and you don't have to worry about missing that crucial 10ms interval to update the score at exactly the right time. If your game runs at 30fps, then you can update this every 30-100 ms -- ten times per second will still be quick enough for the user not to notice.